# Prolog Rule - need help with getting something working?

Tags: prolog

I want to write a rule in prolog, which basically says If a user X has not paid amount Y within 7 days then it will evaluate to payment_outstanding(X).

so far i have something like this:

```
debtpayment_unfulfilled(X) :- owes_money(X, Amountowed, Amountpaid, Days), Days > 7 ,Amountowed > Amountpaid.

owes_money(bob, 500, 0, 3).            //bob borrowed 500 on day 3
```

the rule works, but the problem is the Days + 7 part, for example in the system if someone borrowed on day 3 then the clause will never evaluate to true has Days will always be 3, how can i implement this? do i have to write a seperate rule?? hope you understand what im trying to say.

thanks

Comment: I'm struggling here with your problem space. I'd expect to see the date they borrowed them money being correlated with the current date to determine if current date - borrowed date > 7 days. I'm not sure what "Days" refers to, if it's days since borrowing then that must be calculated and passed back to your check for unfulfilled accounts. This is abstract enough to look like homework.

Comment: I assure you its not homework. I have finished university already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've got you correctly, this is not possible. You should implement in your rule `owes_money(bob, 500, 0, 3).` exact date when bob take the money and then compare it to today's date.

For getting the exact date take a look at this predicate: `get_time(-Time)`. And also for dealing with time you can use:

```
convert_time(+Time, -String)
convert_time(+Time, -Year, -Month, -Day, -Hour, -Minute, -Second, -MilliSeconds)
```

I'm still not sure this is not a homework and I'm a little afraid to give you the solution out of the box.

A fast solution would be to change your predicate `owes_money` like this:

```
owes_money(bob, 500, 0, 2010, 3, 10). %2010 for the year, 3 for the month  ...
```

Then compare this date with the current date:

```
get_time(X), convert_time(X, CurrYear, CurrMonth, CurrDay, _, _, _, _).%CurrYear will give you current year, etc ... . You don't need the hour minutes etc .. that's why are the _
```

Now what is left is to compare CurrYear, CurrMonth and CurrDay with what you get from the owes_money predicate and see how many days have passed.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: I'll have a play with what you've given me. I'm actually researching obligation management, if you look at some of my other questions you will see that I often don't just "ask" someone to do something for me. I have extremely limited knowledge of prolog and am trying my best, like i said before it's not homework! - i havent had any "homework" in years to be honest! Thanks for the reply mate

Comment: Fair enough then ... I will help you further if you need.